# Continuos error when trying to Loop through MySQL Results

Tags: php, mysql, loops, error-handling, foreach

I am trying to loop through a list of MySQL results but I keep receiving the following error: `Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in`. I know this question has been asked several times and I have done a large amount of research but none of the answers I found worked for me. Here is my code:

```
require_once('../../../assets/includes/mysql-connect.php');
$query = "SELECT * FROM customers";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query); 
$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);

$x = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {

    foreach ($array as $key => $subarray) {
        //Do something
    }
}

echo $x;
```

The variable `$num` has 60 results but for some reason I cannot get the code right to loop through the results. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This means that the query failed,but I cant see why.Does that query return something in your mysql client?Also are you connecting with mysql or mysqli?

Comment: Yes, that is the thing. In phpmyAdmin the query `SELECT * FROM customers` returns 60 results. Also, in my code, the variable `$num`, when echoed out prints 60. I have no clue why it says the error is happening

Comment: Do you mean `foreach ($row...` or `foreach ($array...`?

Comment: @MahanGM I mean `foreach ($array`. I did not include it in my code above sorry. The `$array` contains all of the values I am looping though from an API request

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. In my loop I was using the same `$query` and `$result` variables which were overriding the original variables before the loop started!